# Lotus Domino - HTTP Web Server Error - Entry Not Found In Index

Tags: lotus-domino

I have an (browser based) application which runs on Domino 6.5. When a user opens a document, it opens fine and once he clicks on the Save button (which runs @command[FileSave]) it gives 404 error in the browser and this on the server console:

HTTP Web Server: Lotus Notes Exception - Entry not found in index [/app.nsf/0/b5de6bc200881430652578af004118aa?EditDocument&Seq=1]

After Googling a lot, it seems that one of the @dblookup is failing..but I've checked all the fields as many as 5 times and all @dblookup values seem to evaluate correctly. So how do I troubleshoot this error? Is there any notes.ini parameter which enables more trace logs?

Comment: Does the form execute a querySave agent? Maybe logic in that agent fails

Comment: No..there is no querySave agent..its been really frustrating to debug this. The worst debugging system..Sigh!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have to get down to the basics of developer troubleshooting.  If unsure what this means you should make a copy of the current form, so you don't lose anything, then remove everything except a design element and see if you still get the error.  If no error, add another design element and repeat this process until you find the culprit.  If you want to be brave you can do this in big junks, but may have to just get down to field level.

Be aware, I have done this many of times and ended up with the same design form I started troubleshooting when it finally started to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have following options:

1) You can add [FAILSILENT] keyword to your dblookup. Keep in mind, this might not be what you expect.

2) Ensure that database (or views you are using in @DBLookup) is not corrupted.

3) Consider using proper navigation in your application. See following for possible URLs you could use http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/

In addition following might give you some hints, in case if its caused by @DBLookup:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/dblookup-troubleshooting.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try using @iserror function with the @dblookups

Answer (score 0):

If the form in the database contains a field that uses a @DbLookup formula for its choices and the @DbLookup results in an error, then the Web Server will throw a Lotus Notes Exception and return a 404 Error page.

To prevent this issue, proper error handling should be used to catch the possibility of the @DbLookup failing. This can be done by using @IsError on the result of the @DbLookup and return a null string if the result fails.

For example:

```
result:= @Unique(@DbLookup("";"":"";"Main";@Name([CN];@UserName);"UserName"));
@If(@IsError(result);"";result)
```

See [Technote #1193371](https://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21193371) or [Troubleshooting @DbLookup, @DbColumn, GetAllDocumentsByKey](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/dblookup-troubleshooting.htm) (as Egor suggested) for more details.

Comment: All the dblookup are error handled..but still not working! I doubt whether dblookup is the real problem here..

Comment: Alternatively, use this to see what the error is, try: @If(@IsError(result); @text(result); result)